# IQueryable<T> not getting navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't know what I am not getting right here but Navigation properties are not loading using the Inlucde method.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        List<string> navigationProperties =
     GetNavigationProperties<T>();

        var query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            query.Include(navigationProperty);
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }


      private static List<string> GetNavigationProperties<T>() where T : class
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributesData()
                .Any(p => p.AttributeType == typeof(NavigationPropertyAttribute)))
  .Select(n => n.Name).ToList();
    }
```

NavigationPropertyAttribute is a custom attribute and the 
GetNavigationProperties() method returns the list of all navigation properties in the specified type as I could see during debugging.

Comment: "Navigation properties are not loading" isn't a error description. Being more precise helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assign the return value - `Include()` isn't type void

```
query = query.Include(navigationProperty);
```

Comment: Wao. thanks so much. that was the problem. Hours of headache solved!!